# How do I increase the raycast render distance?

Tags: go, raycasting

To learn Golang and have fun with it I've attempted to convert an existing raycaster project from C# into Go: https://github.com/harbdog/raycaster-go

That original project is mainly based on the [lodev raycasting tutorial](https://lodev.org/cgtutor/raycasting.html).

This is my first time creating a raycaster engine, and I've managed to get it into good working order except one main problem: the render distance is too short and I would like to render farther out but I can't see an obvious parameter that would allow that. Any suggestions would be appreciated!

Here's a youtube video demoing it and the render distance problem if you look at when the larger wall in the distance decides to draw in:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HqNorhH37xY

Comment: looks like it might be more of an issue of object management ... I have not looked at your code however ---  are you managing your objects ( walls, etc ) such that they are to be shown or not based on some (faulty) they-appear-inside-my-POV geometry  ?  if yes does your issue go away if you skip over this putative object management logic and just render all objects ... this will be slower yet may avoid the issue at hand ... if so you now know where to troubleshoot the issue

Comment: I'll have to ponder how that might apply to the code since I did have to [write my own draw method](https://github.com/harbdog/raycaster-go/blob/1b05ebec922e1ea6578ab1a0ebf8470626a5e00c/engine/MainGame.go#L242) which wasn't necessary in the C# example I was basing it on.

That said I did notice that render distance was shorter if I reduced my render window height and longer if taller window height (the "h" variable referenced in the lodev tutorial)

Comment: I seem to be on the right track now, I found that if the [scaleY of a texture rectangle](https://github.com/harbdog/raycaster-go/blob/15c29b53b2d04c9a3144768d98c1a808aca96a27/engine/MainGame.go#L256) to be rendered was < 0.25 it wouldn't render at all, which explains why it would render as I got closer. I could force it to render (albeit incorrectly), by making the scaleY = 0.25 if it was less.  
Now I just need to figure out how I can get the Ebiten engine to let me scale something smaller than 0.25.

Comment: It appears to be an Ebiten rendering issue, so I've opened a bug on it https://github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/issues/839

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a [bug in the Ebiten 2D rendering engine](https://github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/issues/839#issuecomment-480535373) that had recently been fixed! Updating to most recent version of Ebiten resolved the issue.

```
go get -u github.com/hajimehoshi/ebiten/...
```

The gist of it was that the older version of Ebiten would not render 1 pixel width images with a Y scaling of less than 0.25, which according to the Ebiten developer the issue was:

> OK so the cause was the mipmap selection with the linear filter: if the determinant of the geometry matrix is small, mipmap is used, but in your case, the mipmap level is so high that the image width becomes 0. This doesn't happen with the nearest filter since mipmap is not used in this case.